# Data analysis of prod Scylla DB without hitting prod?

Tags: cassandra, scylla

Is there a way to extract data from a Scylla database for use in data analysis without directly querying from the production DB?

I want to do large queries against the data but don't want to take down production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical way folks accomplish this, is to build an “analytics DC” in the same physical DC.

So if (one of) your prod DCs is named “dc-west” you would create a new one named “dc-west-analytics” or something like that.  Once the new DCs nodes are out there, change the keyspace to replicate to it.  Run a repair on the new DC, and it should be ready for use.

On the app side or wherever the queries are running from, make sure it uses the LOCAL consistency levels and points to “dc-west-analytics” as its “local” DC.

Answer (score 1):

In ScyllaDB Enterprise, a feature called Workload Prioritization allows you to assign CPU and I/O shares to your analytics and production workloads, isolating them from each other.